# Onclick show button for that title

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Update** 
I would like to have the remove item button be hidden when the item has been removed...

I have 2 buttons one to add an item and one to delete an item from a cart.
Now I would like to have the button to delete the item only to show up once the button to add the item is clicked.

Here is the HTML for the buttons:

```
<button class='add-product' onclick="showDel($(this))" data-product='<?php the_title();?>'>Add Product</button>

<button class="delete-product" onclick="hideDel($(this))" data-product="<?php the_title();?>" style='display:none;'>Remove Product</button>
```

Code I'm using now:

```
    function showDel($this) {
    var dataProduct = $this.attr("data-product");
    $(".delete-product[data-product='" + dataProduct + "']").show();
}
function hideDel($this) {
    $this.hide();
```

But the `Remove Item` button doesn't hide...

HTML Structure:

```
<button class='add-product' onclick="showDel($(this))" data-product='Boot X'>Add Product</button>
<button class="delete-product" data-product="Boot X" style='display:none;'>Remove Product</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using the `onclick="someFunction();"` then do not use `$('.add-product').click(function() {});`. It is the best practice to use only one method for click event. If you use both method for the click event then both will called.

For your question, try this

```
    <button class="cartBtn add-product" data-product="1">Add Product</button> 
<button class="cartBtn delete-product hide" data-product="1">Remove Product</button>
<br>
<button class="cartBtn add-product" data-product="2">Add Product</button> 
<button class="cartBtn delete-product hide" data-product="2">Remove Product</button>
<br>
<button class="cartBtn add-product" data-product="3">Add Product</button> 
<button class="cartBtn delete-product hide" data-product="3">Remove Product</button>
```

JS

```
$('.cartBtn').click(function() {
alert('re');
    var dataProduct = $(this).data("product");

    $('button.add-product[data-product="' + dataProduct + '"]').toggleClass('hide');
        $('button.delete-product[data-product="' + dataProduct + '"]').toggleClass('hide');
```

});

[jsFiddel](https://jsfiddle.net/paragchaure/6nncjp8k/)

Comment: Oh, the Toggle is a good idea! I like it. But A strange thing is happening. The first click doesn't register the toggle. Only if I add more items to the cart.  And if I click on item multiple times. The buttons disappear completely.
Its strange because the jsFiddel does work...

Comment: I have modified my answer

Comment: Excellent! I'll see which one we'll use! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I hope that's what you mean.

Try:

**HTML:**

```
<button class='add-product' onclick="showDel($(this))" data-product='<?php the_title();?>'>Add Product</button>
<button class="delete-product" onclick="hideDel($(this))" data-product="<?php the_title();?>" style='display:none;'>Remove Product</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function showDel($this) {
    var dataProduct = $this.attr("data-product");
    $(".delete-product[data-product='" + dataProduct + "']").show();
}
function hideDel($this) {
    $this.hide();
}
```

**jsfiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/Lxo32trc/3/

Comment: All most. This show all the buttons at once, there are more than one button `class="add-product"` that's why I thought it should be done using the unique data-product....  @rad11

Comment: Impossible , show your responsed HTML structure in question. Look for jsfiddle.

Comment: I want to see the structure of these buttons but loaded with values data-product so copy from browser not from IDE

Comment: Like this? Updated it

Comment: Excellent! One thing. If I press the remove item button. Can we make the `delete-product button` disappear again?

Comment: Why is it not working on my page and it is working in the Fiddle?

Comment: Do you have any errors in console ? Did you add new function hideDel etc.?

Comment: I dont see onclick=hideDel($(this)) do you added it to button?